# Laravel 5.1 FullCalendar table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, fullcalendar, laravel-5.1

Im trying to implement FullCalendar to my Laravel Project using this package https://github.com/maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar
I already created my Model:
EventModel.php

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class EventModel extends Model implements \MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\Event
{

    protected $dates = ['start', 'end'];

    /**
     * Get the event's id number
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Get the event's title
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Is it an all day event?
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isAllDay()
    {
        return (bool)$this->all_day;
    }

    /**
     * Get the start time
     *
     * @return DateTime
     */
    public function getStart()
    {
        return $this->start;
    }

    /**
     * Get the end time
     *
     * @return DateTime
     */
    public function getEnd()
    {
        return $this->end;
    }
}
```

and my controller:

```
public function calendario() {
   $events = [];

    $events[] = \Calendar::event(
        'Event One', //event title
        false, //full day event?
        '2015-02-11T0800', //start time (you can also use Carbon instead of DateTime)
        '2015-02-12T0800', //end time (you can also use Carbon instead of DateTime)
        0 //optionally, you can specify an event ID
    );

    $events[] = \Calendar::event(
        "Valentine's Day", //event title
        true, //full day event?
        new \DateTime('2015-02-14'), //start time (you can also use Carbon instead of DateTime)
        new \DateTime('2015-02-14'), //end time (you can also use Carbon instead of DateTime)
        'stringEventId' //optionally, you can specify an event ID
    );

    $eloquentEvent = EventModel::first(); //EventModel implements MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\Event

    $calendar = \Calendar::addEvents($events) //add an array with addEvents
        ->addEvent($eloquentEvent, [ //set custom color fo this event
            'color' => '#800',
        ])->setOptions([ //set fullcalendar options
            'firstDay' => 1
        ])->setCallbacks([ //set fullcalendar callback options (will not be JSON encoded)
            'viewRender' => 'function() {alert("Callbacks!");}'
        ]); 

    return view('hello', compact('calendar'));
}
```

But im getting this error when I go to my route:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'petdate.event_models' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from
>   `event_models` limit 1)

Do I have to add a table?

Comment: The error says that a table has to exist, so yes, you have to add a table.

Comment: But wich fields does the table require?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow your heart, no i'm kidding follow your model function:

```
protected $dates = ['start', 'end'];



 /**
     * Get the event's id number
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Get the event's title
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }
```

There you can see you need an id and a title, one is int and the other one is string. :)

Comment: Thanks <3 I followed my heart :P it worked I just had to add a row to the table :)

Comment: Told you, i always follow my heart and everything works except my code but that's another story. You welcome anytime. <3 :)